# indefinite differentiation issues

Tags: calculus

I'm studying for finals and have encountered an issue with a problem. I would greatly appreciate help in finding where I screwed up.
$$\int \frac {cos27t^{1/2}dt}{(27t)^{1/2}}$$
I changed it to $$\int (cos27t^{1/2})(27t^{-1/2})dt$$
and set $$u=27t^{1/2}$$
with $$\frac {du}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}(27t^{-1/2}) $$
and modified that to $$2du=(27t^{-1/2})dt$$
I then plugged th+e 'u' into the original formula, and got 
$$2\int cos(u)du$$
I then integrated, and got 
$$2sin(u)+C$$
I then plugged the original values in, and got 
$$2sin(27t^{1/2}+C)$$
However, the program I am using tells me this is incorrect.
Can someone please tell me where I screwed up?
Thanks

Comment: $27t^{1/2} \neq (27 t)^{1/2}$ and also $2\sin (u)+C \neq 2\sin (u+C)$.  Please check your typesetting; bracket placement matters.

Comment: So would it be $$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{2} (27t^{-1/2})$$? I fail to see how that makes a difference

Comment: **The bracket placement throughout the question is inconsistent**  Please improve the question by checking your typesetting.

Comment: I think I fixed it, did I get them all?

Comment: $\displaystyle\int \frac {\cos27t^{1/2}}{(27t)^{1/2}}\operatorname d t \neq \int (\cos27t^{1/2})(27t^{-1/2})\operatorname d t$

Comment: But then how can I substitute?

Comment: 1. ensure you have copied the question correctly (with brackets in the right places).  2. use $u=t^{1/2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32915/discussion-between-daniel-furhang-and-graham-kemp).

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$I=\int \frac{\cos \left(27 \sqrt{t}\right)}{ \sqrt{27t} }\,dt$$ start changing variable $27 \sqrt{t}=x$, that is to say $t=\frac{x^2}{729}$, $dt=\frac{2 x}{729}\,dx$. This makes $$I=\int \frac{2 \cos (x)}{81 \sqrt{3}}\,dx=\frac{2 \sin (x)}{81 \sqrt{3}}+C=\frac{2 \sin (27 \sqrt{t})}{81 \sqrt{3}}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{\cos\left(27\sqrt{t}\right)}{\sqrt{27t}}\space\text{d}t=$$
$$\frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{\cos\left(27\sqrt{t}\right)}{\sqrt{t}}\space\text{d}t=$$

---

Subtitute $u=27\sqrt{t}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{27}{2\sqrt{t}}\space\text{d}t$:

---

$$\frac{2}{81\sqrt{3}}\int\cos(u)\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\frac{2\sin\left(u\right)}{81\sqrt{3}}+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{2\sin\left(27\sqrt{t}\right)}{81\sqrt{3}}+\text{C}$$